# Is it possible to have a Twitter Bootstrap 3 modal "slide across" into a new modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is not the same as just having a modal slide in from the side.

I cannot find how say I click "forgotten password" in my example a new modal will slide across with the forgotten password form.

I was thinking this could possibly be done using a slider within the modal and set the "right arrow" to forgotten password. then the left arrow to "back".

The only information i could find online was how to get the original modal to slide in from the side not a second one.

Using my terrible Photoshop skills i have tried to make a picture of what will happen. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using tabs from bootstrap 3. You can make these fade in so that it smoothly swaps in.

[Here is a link to it.](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)